# XPages - Dojo Validation Text Box - Customize Message

Tags: dojo, xpages, lotus-notes

When using a Dojo Validation Text Box, if I try to submit the XPage without entering any value into the Dojo validation Text Box, I see the message "This value is required". Is there any way of customizing this message? (I wish to have this message in another language)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define your customized message as a dojoAttribute:

```
<xe:djValidationTextBox
    id="djValidationTextBox1"
    value="#{viewScope.test}"
    required="true">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute
            name="missingMessage"
            value="Your customized required message!">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
</xe:djValidationTextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm traying to get this working also with a Dojo Filtering Select control but so far with no luck. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Dojo Filtering Select control does work the same way: `required="true"` and same dojoAttribute. Or do mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

I completely stopped using the built in validations once I found this script by White / Girrard / Valand / Mottolo:
[A Better Method For XPages SSJS Form Validation](http://planetlotus.org/profiles/don-mottolo_101188)

It gives you the ability to react to any state of the input values and I prefer the centralised approach over tweaking inside the single controls themselves.